# Godaddy Seal static image without javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a secure **https** enabled website
I am using static image instead of the javascript provided by godaddy for showing godaddy seal
Is there any security or other problem for that?

Comment: Is the static image URL `https` as well? Some browsers are strict about loading `http` resources on `https` websites

Comment: Jeff the static image url is also https  but I am just woring about if there is any security concern if i dont use the javascript code provided by godaddy to show their seal

Comment: As with any seal, the implied security is in the mind of the beholder ;) and certainly, by linking to a static image rather than (theoretically malicious) javascript, your page will be marginally more secure anyways